# Spring Cloud Function on Google Cloud + SQL

Tags: sql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build a web app on Google Cloud platform and I want to make it as cheap as possible. I’m not expecting high load on my application so I don’t want to run a Compute instance because most of the time it will be idle. So I decided to try Cloud functions.
The scenario:

1. Webhook sends http request to Cloud function.
2. Cloud function connects to database, creates a record and send the message to pub/sub topic.
   The message from pub/sub topic may be processed by another app, it doesn’t matter now.

The questions are:

a) Is this a valid scenario for Google Cloud function to connect to SQL instance? I tried to find a sample of some function connecting to database but there’s nothing. However GCP docs explain how to connect to GCP SQL instance from function.

b) Is this a good idea to use Java as runtime and Spring Boot Framework for this purpose? I don’t want to write the code on pure JDBC, however using jpa library may lead to huge cold boot time.

Thanks

Comment: Before answering in details, your Cloud SQL database is based on which DB engine? Do you know another language than Java? (Not a problem, just if i work on a sample, just to be sure to work for the right thing!)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere my Cloud SQL database is based on PostgreSQL. But it doesn't matter really. What really matters is whether Google Cloud Function is a good choice to resolve my problem or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions is single purpose. Your process is clearly single purpose. Cloud Functions is the right choice.

However, Java Cloud Functions is a really fresh beta (only 10 days). So, Google Cloud beta are reliable but if you look for a service quickly in GA, Java is not the right choice for this.

If GA is a requirement, 2 alternatives:

- Use Cloud Run (very similar to Cloud Functions and with the "same price" (at least for your case)). I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e)
- Use another language (Go, Python, Node)

No, your question about the cold start is real. I'm a spring boot fan and, and I switch from Java to Python (and then to Go, I don't like dynamic type language) because of Cold start. My first pain was on Cloud Run because I was an Alpha tester and I wrote [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/java-frameworks-performances-on-cloud-run-eb243fd84a5c).

Spring is a CPU and Memory monster. The cold start are awful. The trade off of an easy to use framework. Today, you can set 2CPU in Cloud Run or set a min instance if you want to minimize this cold start, but it's not free!

So, your process seems very simple.

- Does a strong framework like Spring is required for "only this"? Raw SQL works well, JPA is not always the right solution!
- Did you think about micronaut alternative? The annotation and the behavior is very close to Spring but there is no dynamic loading and thus a quick start.
- Did you consider any other languages? Java can be quick (start and processing), but in any cases, it costs in memory usage (250Mb VS 15Mb in Go for the same hello world). For a simple development, it's a good playground for testing new things. And, because of the small size, it will be easy to maintain by anyone who doesn't know the language.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is fully answers my question. I’ll try go or Python.